# Remove characters after the last appearance of a delimiter in a string

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to remove the characters in a string after the last occurrence of a delimiter?

I have looked into the following questions.

[Split string by last separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255706/split-string-by-last-separator) - In this case, the characters before the last occurrence are omitted. But I just need the opposite of this.

[Remove last characters from a string in C#. An elegant way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098556/remove-last-characters-from-a-string-in-c-an-elegant-way) - Here the characters after the first occurrence of the delimiter are removed.

For e.g.
I have a string

```
"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111\file1.txt"
```

The result I expect is

```
"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111"
```

Note: This is just an example. I need a solution to work in other cases too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `String.Remove()` method.

```
string test = @"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111\file1.txt";
string result = test.Remove (test.LastIndexOf ('\\'));
```

The value stored in `result` will be

```
"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using LastIndexOf

```
string str =@"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111\file1.txt"
str= str.SubString(0,str.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

If you are looking for something generic then create extension method

```
public static string GetStringBeforeLastIndex(this string str,string delimeter)
{
  return str.SubString(0,str.LastIndexOf(delimeter));
}
```

Now you just have to call the method

```
string str =@"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111\file1.txt"
    str = str.GetStringBeforeLastIndex("\\"); you can pass any delimeter

 string str =@"asdd-asdasd-sdfsdf-hfghfg"
        str = str.GetStringBeforeLastIndex("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be the safest way

```
string Pathname = @"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111\file1.txt";
string Result = Path.GetDirectoryName(Pathname);
```

Comment: that was just an example (file path). i would like the solution to work for any string. i.e i can have a string like "edfe-fefe-geer-edew". the result must be "edfe-fefe-geer-

Comment: @madmax There's no `'\'` in the above example

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the C# 8.0 [Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-):

```cs
string path = @"D:\dir1\subdir1\subdir11\subdir111\file1.txt";
int lastSlashIndex = path.LastIndexOf("\\");
string result = path[0..lastSlashIndex];
```

The value of `result` will be

```
"D:\\dir1\\subdir1\\subdir11\\subdir111"
```